# Https Mismatch for registry.npmjs.org blocks maven download

Tags: maven, npm

Have you run into a problem with npmjs.org?  I figure, I must be doing something wrong (like using the wrong url) because https for this site probably isn't broken.... right?

Npm download fails with:

```
Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:
install-node-and-npm (install-frontend-build-tools) on project xxx: 
Could not download Node.js: Could not download 
https://registry.npmjs.org/v0.12.1/node-v0.12.1-linux-x64.tar.gz: 
hostname in certificate didn't match: <registry.npmjs.org> != <a.sni.fastly.net> OR <a.sni.fastly.net> OR 
<a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net> ->
```

I configured the frontend-maven-plugin thus:

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <version>0.0.23</version>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <!-- get latest node/npm/ember tools -->
      <execution>
        <id>install-frontend-build-tools</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <nodeVersion>v0.12.1</nodeVersion>
          <npmVersion>2.5.1</npmVersion>
          <downloadRoot>https://registry.npmjs.org/</downloadRoot> <!-- http://mvn.corp.attivio.com/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/ -->
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Why have you configured `downloadRoot` to be `registry.npmjs.org`? frontend-maven-plugin's documentation [states](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#installing-node-and-npm) that `downloadRoot` should be where one can download Node.js and `npm`... Node.js is not in the `npm` registry.

Comment: Kenan, Ah, I read the source and saw that I must add these repos to my npm-all repo  node: "http://nodejs.org/dist/" and for "http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/".    I checked out the mojo source and hunted down the default setting in [NodeAndNPMInstaller.java](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/blob/master/frontend-plugin-core/src/main/java/com/github/eirslett/maven/plugins/frontend/lib/NodeAndNPMInstaller.java)    Thanks.

Comment: Using http://register.npmjs.org gets around the cert issues but still doesn't seem to work.  I'll post that in a different question though for clarity.